# StrongSwan IPsec VPN slow connection speed on Manjaro Linux(Arch)

Tags: arch-linux, vpn, manjaro, ipsec, strongswan

On Manjaro Linux (arch), the speed of connecting to corporate resources under vpn (ipsec) dropped to almost 0, but everything was fine before
I have already tried different configurations, but nothing helped.
At the same time, vpn works fine on Android and there are no such problems

ipsec.conf:

```
config setup
    # strictcrlpolicy=yes
    # uniqueids = no
 
conn NAME
    dpdaction=restart
    dpddelay=30
    dpdtimeout=90
    fragmentation=yes
    leftsourceip=%config
    keyexchange=ikev2
    eap_identity=***
    leftauth=eap-mschapv2
    rightauth=pubkey
    right=***
    rightsubnet=***
    auto=add
```

/etc/strongswan.conf:

```
charon {
    threads = 10240
    #load_modular = yes
    plugins {
        include strongswan.d/charon/*.conf
    }
}

include strongswan.d/*.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this solution helped me I reduced the MTU and everything returned to normal.

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=244606

> I find the issue ! It was related to MTU.

```
sudo ip link set dev wlp3s0 mtu 1328
```